# How to alter content when paste in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, copy-paste, paste

I'm learning Javascript on [The Modern JavaScript Tutorial](https://javascript.info/), sometimes I had to copy some sample code on that website and paste it into WebStorm to test, but the sample codes using `alert()` function to print.

```
let recipeMap = new Map([
  ['cucumber', 500],
  ['tomatoes', 350],
  ['onion',    50]
]);

// iterate over keys (vegetables)
for (let vegetable of recipeMap.keys()) {
  alert(vegetable); // cucumber, tomatoes, onion
}
```

Is there any way to change `alert(something)` to `console.log(something)` when I paste.

If WebStorm has no abilities to do this, other tools on windows platform also acceptable.

Comment: There is no such feature in the IDE. You can use Find/Replace to replace the `alert` calls in the pasted content

Comment: @lena I want this operation to be done automatically